# I can't get pagination to show up in every page on a GridView with a list as source

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, pagination

I'm trying to set the pagination for a GridView that has a LINQ generated list, but though the function I wrote to handle `OnPageIndexChanging` attribute in the GridView shows the records as planned, the footer with the page numbers dissapears when I navigate to any page. I'd appreciate some orientation on this as I'm new to C# and asp and I don't have a clue as to why this is happening. I realize there are lots of ways of doing this, some involving `new GridViewRow()` and even generating an `EmptyDataTemplate` with custom html, but I don't quite understand what those functions do. I'd appreciate if someone commented on my code, what I'm missing.

I have set the GridView with AllowPaging true of course, and my Pager Settings are: mode NumericFirstLast, and Visible=true. When I debug the code the footer visibility shows it's true yet the page numbers dissapear. 
My asp is like this (not all of it I only include the definition of the GridView):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridCol" runat="server" DataKeyNames="identMovimiento" 
                    AllowPaging="True" ShowFooter="True"     OnDataBound="GridCol_DataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="PaginarCol">
```

And the PaginarCol function is like so (I roughly repeat here some code I use in the Page_Load function, because I want to populate the GridView again with the same source:

```
protected void PaginarCol(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
        GridCol.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        int numResultados, inicioResultados;
        matriculas identificacion = new     obtenerMatricula().getMatriculaDatos(User.Identity.Name);
        int idusuario = identificacion.matriculaId;
        obtenerAdeudos Lista = new obtenerAdeudos();
        List<Adeudos> ListaAdeudos = Lista.getAdeudosCol(idusuario);
        int maxResultados = ListaAdeudos.Count();
        numResultados = 10; inicioResultados = GridCol.PageIndex*10;
        List<Adeudos> filasAdeudos =     ListaAdeudos.Skip(inicioResultados).Take(numResultados).ToList();
        GridCol.DataSource = filasAdeudos;
        GridCol.DataBind();
        GridCol.BottomPagerRow.Visible = true;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page numbers are disappearing because in the page index changing event (`PaginarCol()`), you are binding exactly one page of data, because of the `Skip()` and `Take()` calls. Since the grid is bound with only one page of data, there is no need for page numbers, thus they disappear.

My guess, since you did not post the `Page_Load` code, is that you are binding the whole list initially and not using `Skip()` and `Take()` to only get the one page of data. This would actually cause the grid to realize that there are pages of data instead of just one, thus the page numbers appear when the grid is first loaded.

If you want your existing code to actually keep showing the page numbers, then remove this entire line:

```
List<Adeudos> filasAdeudos =     
    ListaAdeudos.Skip(inicioResultados).Take(numResultados).ToList();
```

Now instead just bind directly to `ListaAdeudos`, like this:

```
GridCol.DataSource = ListaAdeudos;
```

Since your `PaginarCol()` method is updating the grid's page index value, via this line:

```
GridCol.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
```

Rebinding the grid will take care of the correct page number being selected and all of the page numbers continuing to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks! The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to do the actual pagination, because I read it's enough with simply doing `GridView.PageIndex=e.NewPageIndex` but then I must bind something to the GridView, don't I? Otherwise the page links show exactly the same list and clicking on them won't make any difference

Comment: @gerardoflores - `GridCol.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;` should handle updating the grid's page correctly upon changing the page index. All that is necessary in the `PaginarCol()` method is to set the `NewPageIndex` to the grid's `PageIndex` and re-bind the grid.

Comment: Thank you, I realize now I was making a storm in a glass of water. Don't know how I missed that!